# Cannot add environment variables in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

For an entire day I have been tryng to add an environment variable to linux ad it isn't working. This is the [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvirontVariables) that I am following. This is what is written in the *.profile* file.

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_51
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
LARAVEL=/home/user/.composer/vendor/bin
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$LARAVEL
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export LARAVEL
export PATH
```

I am running the file. But when I run `echo $PATH` I am not getting the `$LARAVEL` path. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you logged out and logged in?  Also try to update your .bashrc file instead.  I think that .profile is only used for the ksh shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try to source the file, like;

```
$ source yourfilename
```

In Unix/Linux (unlike in Windows) a program cannot affect the environment of the parent process.  When you are running it as a regular shellscript it becomes a subprocess of the parent, and it will affect only it's own environment and not that of the parent.

Using the keyword `source` (or using the dot `.`) will instruct your process to executed the shell script directly rather than `fork` a new subprocess.

Comment: this works. But when I close the terminal and open it again, it doesn't work.

Comment: try to rename the file to `~/.bash_profile` and set permissions to 644 (chmod)

Answer (score 0):

In a command line, you can just add your path like below where `~/.bashrc` is your bash profile. Note that the name may differ in your case.

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH":/path/to/folder/' >> ~/.bashrc
```

You nee to refresh your bash profile

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You should visit this article for more details: [Set Environment Variables in Linux](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Could you please detail that a little more?

Comment: visit: https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/